# ngx-smart-modal - How to interact with component from class reference?

Tags: angular

When I open a modal using a class reference via...

```
// component
this.ngxSmartModalService.create('myModal2', MyComponent).open();
```

How can I interact with that component?  How can I provide a value to an @Input or call a method on the component?  Basically, any examples or tutorials on how to meaningfully interact with the component will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To pass from input variables to a component created in your typescript, you can do so with the ResolverFactory component and the instance entry.

Assuming that your component has a `data` input:

```js
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);

const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
(<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
```

More details on [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: ngx-smart-modal creates a component from a class name, so I would need to know more about how they are creating the component.  They don't accept an already-created component.

Answer (score 0):

Actually dynamic components with template bindings couldn't be rendered properly. It seems it's a limitation for many libraries. I created [an issue about this topic](https://github.com/biig-io/ngx-smart-modal/issues/235) in order to fix it as soon as possible.

Someone did a great fix and we will try to release it really soon.